# An image on local machine is displayed properly on image viewer but is not read properly while using cv2.imread()?

Tags: python, image, opencv, base64

I am sending a base64 image to a `flask` server. The base64 image is then decoded and saved on my local machine using file handling. After saving the file, I use `opencv 2.0` function `imread` to read the image and `imshow` to display it. But it displays a fully black image(with the numpy array being all zeroes). The image is displayed properly using an image viewer.
What could be possible solutions?

I have tried replacing OpenCV with `matplotlib`, but it doesn't work either. Even added imread_unchanged so as the returned image is not cropped.

```
image_64_encoded="contains base64 encoded image"
fh = open("imageToSave.png", "w")
fh.write(image_64_encoded.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
rel_path = "../shape-detection/imageToSave.png"
abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
print("\n",abs_file_path,"\n\n")
image = cv2.imread(abs_file_path)
print(image);
cv2.imshow('image',image)
```

The expected result must be the same as displayed by the image viewer. But it displays a pure black image.

Actual image from image viewer

[image: Actual image from image viewer]

image displayed by cv2.imshow()

[image: image displayed by cv2.imshow()]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is all in the alpha channel not the RGB channels.

You'll need to use:

```
image = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

and look in the 4th channel (alpha):

```
usefulchannel = image[:,:,3]
```